# How to find all hidden symbols on a keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-languages, special-characters, symbols

OK I constantly see articles on how to type special characters using the character map or the codes or whatever ways. But often there is a way to type a symbol, but you just don't know under which key it´s hidhing or which extra keys to hit to access them (i.e. recently discovered alt gr bringing new values, despite being a software engineer...)

So is there a way to find out how to find all of the functions or anything a keyboard layout offers?

We have many languages and many layouts, each has itsown special ways of using it, so where do I learn about each keyboard? Would be great if there were some kind of diagrams or maps explaining the whole thing, something like a reference of each keyboard layout or something like that.

Comment: There is no complete list for all languages that I know of, even some programs like MS Office have their own also.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer  to _Windows: Detect if right alt generates Ctrl+Alt (AltGr) in current layout_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59041425/3439404). If it can help: I have written a script which returns a human-friendly list of currently installed _Handle Keyboard Layout_s…

Comment: Take a look to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1435915/376602) as well. Note link to [Windows Keyboard Layouts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/windows-keyboard-layouts).